# Disable search button press during ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I have a simple ProgressDialog but I realized if I press the search button the dialog will be dismiss. What can I do to disable search button press during this process?

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
dialog.setTitle("Working in progress");
dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();
```

I put this and it didn't work.

```
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this){
    @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
            return false;
    }
    };
```

This don't work either.

```
    dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                return true; // Pretend we processed it
            }
            return false; // Any other keys are still processed as normal
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        return false;
}
```

in the activity, instead of the dialog.

Edit: Also try adding the key listener code to the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: does the key listener detect anything when you press search? have you tried debugging to see if it enters the listener or logging the keycode?

Comment: and you also have tried overriding onSearchRequested for both dialog and activity at the same time?

Comment: How to I tell? I saw in Locat there's a msg "No keyboard for ID 0" and "Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin" but not sure if they are related.

Comment: you could put a breakpoint in the line with keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH and examine the keyCode (or add a log line before, if you don't want to use the debugger). If the code is not being executed, try with other key, for example back button. if nothing is executed then you know the problem is the keylistener... this regarding the keyListener solution, I don't know why the other approach doesn't work.

Comment: I am not familiar with debugger, I put a Toast before keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH and I did not see the Toast, so does it mean the setOnKeyListener didn't get executed at all?

Comment: probably, but your toast code might also be wrong. you can try also adding this line: Log.d("blabla", "pressed key: " + keyCode); above the if and check if you see something in the log. Maybe you have to add the listener to the activity instead of the dialog

Comment: I have toast all over the place for testing so it should be ok. How do I add listener to the activity? Any example? I'm using tab, this dialog belongs to one of the tab with has it's own activity so I guess that is not related?

Comment: Edited my post. It should not be related with tabs, just add it to the tab/activity you're currently in.

Comment: >< I am so stupid! I have 2 dialog and I place the code in the other one. onSearchRequested() is not working puting the listener in the dialog works ok.